# WebApplicationFactory always return 404 (not found) for controllers calls in .net core 6

Tags: c#, .net, testing, xunit

In .net core 6, startup.cs has been removed, the integration testing I used before doesn't work anymore as is. I need to do an update.

In my API (program.cs), I added:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("constructionCompanyAPI.IntegrationTests")]
```

and here is the Integration.Tests csproj:

[csprojImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkeB7.png)

I created a ConstructionCompanyControllersTests.cs like:

```
public class ConstructionCompanyControllerTests
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public ConstructionCompanyControllerTests()
    {
        _client = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    var dbContextOptions = services
                    .SingleOrDefault(service => service.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ConstructionCompanyDbContext>));

                    services.Remove(dbContextOptions);

                    services.AddDbContext<ConstructionCompanyDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("ConstructionCompanyDb"));
                });
            })
            .CreateClient();
    }
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10")]
    [InlineData("?pageNumber=1&pageSize=5")]
    public async Task GetAll_WithQueryParameters_ReturnsOkResult(string queryParams)
    {
        // act

        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/constructionCompany" + queryParams);

        // assert

        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

When I launch the API, every thing works correctly, I'm to see my controller in Swagger and call the get with a code 200 returns.

So each time the test fails here:

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/constructionCompany" + queryParams);
```

The response always get a 404 error (not found).

```
Expected response.StatusCode to be HttpStatusCode.OK {value: 200}, but found HttpStatusCode.NotFound {value: 404}.
```

What should I do to make it works correctly?

Thanks

Edit:
The Entire program.cs file:

[program.cs](https://pastebin.com/8qtdzv4F)

Comment: What is in `Program`? I would have expected that to be `Startup`

Comment: @DavidG I added the entire program.cs file

Answer (score 8):

I added "args" to the method and it worked

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Comment: dude...this little change and my day is saved :-)
thx

Comment: it saved me! I find the `args` provides: 1. env name, 2. content dir, 3. app name. I think the content dir works for this issue

Comment: I was searching for hours :/

Comment: This saved my day, thank you! This happened to me after converting my minimal API's to MVC controllers, but now by passing the `args` it works again